# Get "gs_secret_key" and "gs_access_key" values for Google Bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ansible, cloud-computing, infrastructure, google-cloud-storage

I need to create a directory in a Google Cloud Bucket using Ansible. I would like to know where I can find the values to complete "gs_secret_key" and "gs_access_key" to use "gc_storage" module in Ansible.

```
- name: Create a bucket with key as directory
  become: no
  gc_storage:
    bucket: "my-bucket-name"
    mode: "create"
    region: "US-EAST1"
    object: "/test_directory/"
    gs_access_key: "321012345678-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com"
    gs_secret_key: "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIblashblah...blahblahmow=\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n"
```

I'm not sure about the values that I set in the Ansible script. With the current values I get an error message saying:

> GSResponseError: 403 Forbidden\nSignatureDoesNotMatchThe request
>   signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided.
>   Check your Google secret key and signing method.PUT\n\n\nWed, 10 Oct
>   2018 16:26:00 GMT\n/my-bucket-name/

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just change value of **gs_access_key**, it isn't private_key_id value but **private_key_id** that your service account key.

Comment: ok, but where could I find that service account key in the GCP web interface? thank you!

Comment: Here its a better refer. -> https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys